# Problem with PHP version on Ubuntu on Windows when installing Drush

Tags: composer, 10

I'm trying to install Drupal 10 with DDEV with these instructions: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#drupal.
I'm on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL2).
Ubuntu version: 20.04.
Windows 10.
When I try to run the command `ddev composer require drush/drush` I get errors.

```
Using version ^11.4 for drush/drush
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drush/drush
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core 10.0.0 requires php >=8.1.0 -> your php version (8.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0 requires drupal/core 10.0.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended is locked to version 10.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require drush/drush:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require drush/drush:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
composer [require drush/drush] failed, composer command failed: exit status 2. stderr=
```

I upgraded PHP. `php -v` reports I installed PHP 8.2.0.

How can Composer say I am using PHP 8.0.14?

Comment: `ddev config --php-version 8.1 && ddev restart`, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/configuration/config/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re executing `PHP` on your local machine, which has PHP 8.2 installed. You’re executing `composer` inside the VM, which has PHP 8.0 installed. You need to upgrade PHP inside your VM.

See [Extending and Customizing Environments](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/) for instructions to do that in DDev.

Comment: This and you could even simply have Apache running a different PHP version than on the command line.